# According to the state postulate ,the state of a simple compressible system can be completely specified by 2 independent intensive properties

Tags: thermodynamics

My doubts are.....

1. What is a simple compressible system?
2. Why can't I use two dependent intensive properties to specify the thermodynamic state.
3. Why can't I use extensive property like total volume to specify the thermodynamic state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [According to the state postulate ,the state of a simple compressible system is completely specified by 2 independent intensive properties](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/608827/according-to-the-state-postulate-the-state-of-a-simple-compressible-system-is-c)

Comment: Don't post the same question more than once.

Comment: @letsintegreat the link gives page not found, but the question is interesting: can I say that a simple compressible system Is a system fully defined by p,V and T? Is this a good definition?